# Sharing domain validation logic in application layer by using FluentValidation

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, fluentvalidation

In our domain  we have Student , each student has first name,last name and student number. Business rule for student number is that , student number can be any number from 1 to 99999. Since this validation belongs to the domain layer , I wrote a class for that , such as ;

```
public class StudentNumber : ValueObject
    {
        public StudentNumber(int value)
        {
            if (value <= 0 || value > 99999)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    nameof(value),
                    "Student number must be in range of (0,9999]");
            }

            Value = value;
        }


        public int Value { get; private set; }

        public static implicit operator StudentNumber(int value)
        {
            return new StudentNumber(value);
        }
    }
```

However, It is better to validate input at application layer. Therefore, I ended up with a validation class ( by using FluentValidation library) that can be found below;

```
public class CreateStudentCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateStudentCommand>
    {
        public CreateStudentCommandValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(m => m.StudentNumber)
                .ExclusiveBetween(0, 100000)
                .WithMessage(ErrorCodes.InvalidStudentNo);
        }
    }
```

In CreateStudentCommand , StudentNumber propertys datatype is integer.

This validator works, however it violates DRY rule. Since I repeat validation logic in both domain layer and application.

Question is; What is the best practice of using domain validation code in FluentValidation validator class ?

Comment: Discussions on patterns and other design concerns aren't really a good fit for stackoverflow, they are subjective and not quantifiable (usually) and inherently just opinion based or even worse, based on someone else's opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two numbers are really in different models – the request model and the domain model.  In re-reading the question and my original answer, I think I see the mismatch here.

Front end validation should be limited to basic data types.  If you’re expecting an integer, ensure the caller sent an integer, dates are dates, and strings are strings.  This is the responsibility of the Controller (or whatever receives the request directly from user).  If the user sends an invalid integer, it is rejected at this level. No range checks are done here, we only check to ensure the request is well-formed.

The controller then creates a command.  The role of the Command is to communicate the user’s desire to the domain logic, which performs business logic to execute that desire.  We assume the user really does want to create a student with the given number therefore the Command should communicate this desire to the Domain, i.e. no validation of range should be in the Command.  Command validation is typically done just with constructor arguments of the appropriate type.

The Domain logic tries to carry out the users’ desire and create a new student with an invalid number.  The Domain decides this is not a valid number and throws the exception at this level, making the Command execution fail.  The controller senses the failed Command execution and returns an appropriate failure to the caller (or, if command execution is async, processes the error in the appropriate way).

Your initial instinct was correct that you were violating DRY.  This can be shown by changing the business rule to allow a broader range.  This single business rule change would require two code changes, thus proving you were repeating yourself.